# groupby sum in Pandas/Python with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

df_have

```
ID  AMT     REL_NUM HDR_NUM
3   0.02    2.0      2.0    
4   2.00    2.0      4.0    
5   0.00    1.0      5.0    
1   0.00    5.0      1.0    
2   19.7    1.0      2.0
```

df_want

```
ID  AMT     REL_NUM HDR_NUM CALCULATION
3   0.02    2.0      2.0      (19.7+0.02+2.00)
4   2.00    2.0      4.0      (2.00)
5   0.00    1.0      5.0      (0.00+0.00)
1   0.00    5.0      1.0      (0.00+19.7)
2   19.7    1.0      2.0      (19.7+0.02+2.00)
```

Trying to create a new column 'CALCULATION' but the logic is a bit tricky. 
The calculation should be the SUM of the AMT field dependent on the ID, REL_NUM and HDR_NUM fields.

Step 1- Check the HDR_NUM field and get the corresponding AMT value where ID=HDR_NUM
Step 2- Add in all AMT fields where the REL_NUM= HDR_NUM

For the first row, this would be summing the AMT fields for ID= 2,3 and 4.

Sample code which needs to be updated. I tried a groupby first but I am having trouble getting it to cater for both steps described above:

```
df_want['CALCULATION']=df_have.groupby(['ID','HDR_NUM'])['AMT'].transform('sum')+ ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `.map`. For the second one, you'll need to groupby to get the sum within each `'REL_NUM'`

```
df['num1'] = df.HDR_NUM.map(df.set_index('ID').AMT)
df['num2'] = df.HDR_NUM.map(df.groupby('REL_NUM').AMT.sum())

df['calculation'] = df.num1.add(df.num2, fill_value=0)
```

#### Output: (leaving the helper columns in for clarity)

```
   ID    AMT  REL_NUM  HDR_NUM  num1   num2  calculation
0   3   0.02      2.0      2.0  19.7   2.02        21.72
1   4   2.00      2.0      4.0   2.0    NaN         2.00
2   5   0.00      1.0      5.0   0.0   0.00         0.00
3   1   0.00      5.0      1.0   0.0  19.70        19.70
4   2  19.70      1.0      2.0  19.7   2.02        21.72
```

---

In the case that you do not want to duplicate `AMT` because `HDR_NUM == ID == REL_NUM`, you can only sum a subset for the `groupby` so that you do not double-count:

```
df['num1'] = df.HDR_NUM.map(df.set_index('ID').AMT)
df['num2'] = df.HDR_NUM.map(df[df.REL_NUM != df.ID].groupby('REL_NUM').AMT.sum())
df['calculation'] = df.num1.add(df.num2, fill_value=0)
```

#### Output: (swapped IDs for the first and last row)

```
   ID    AMT  REL_NUM  HDR_NUM  num1  num2  calculation
0   2   0.02      2.0      2.0  0.02   2.0         2.02
1   4   2.00      2.0      4.0  2.00   NaN         2.00
2   5   0.00      1.0      5.0  0.00   0.0         0.00
3   1   0.00      5.0      1.0  0.00  19.7        19.70
4   3  19.70      1.0      2.0  0.02   2.0         2.02
```

Comment: Thanks @ALollz, a follow up, suppose the first ID was 2 and the last ID was 3. In that case, I would want the CALCULATION to be 0.02+2.00. Using your method, it would duplicate the 0.02 entry since num1=0.02, and num2=2.02. Can you cater for this exception?

Comment: Thanks @ALollz, one last update if possible. There is another column before ID called CONTRACT, that identifies this subset of rows from a greater set of rows (i.e. the CONTRACT column would be all 1 for all 5 rows above, but would be 2 for the next few rows etc.). When we run num1 (and num2), we want it to reference the ID column for that specific CONTRACT. Tried df['num1'] = df.HDR_NUM.map(df.set_index(['CONTRACT','ID']).AMT) but this resulted in all NULLs

Comment: @babz I think that would be better answered in a new question, since it is a bit involved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838598/pandas-python-complex-conditional-sum