# Pandas/Python complex, conditional sum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

df_have

```
CONTRACT ID  AMT     REL_NUM HDR_NUM
1         1   0.00    0      1    
1         2   33.85   1      2    
1         3   0.72    2      2    
1         4   0.87    1      1    
1         5   1.67    1      2
```

df_want

```
CONTRACT ID  AMT     REL_NUM HDR_NUM CALCULATION
1         1   0.00    0      1        (0.00+33.85+0.87+1.67)
1         2   33.85   1      2        (33.85+0.72)
1         3   0.72    2      2        (33.85+0.72)
1         4   0.87    1      1        (0.00+33.85+0.87+1.67)
1         5   1.67    1      2        (33.85+0.72)
```

df_getting

```
CONTRACT ID  AMT     REL_NUM HDR_NUM CALCULATION
1         1   0.00    0      1        21.75
1         2   33.85   1      2        2.00
1         3   0.72    2      2        19.75
1         4   0.87    1      1        33.85
1         5   1.67    1      2        0.00
```

Trying to create a new column 'CALCULATION' but the logic is a bit tricky. The calculation should be the SUM of the AMT field dependent on the CONTRACT, ID, REL_NUM and HDR_NUM fields.

Step 1- Check the HDR_NUM field and get the corresponding AMT value where ID=HDR_NUM AND the CONTRACT field is the same

Step 2- Add in all AMT fields where the REL_NUM= HDR_NUM for the same CONTRACT

For the first row, this would be summing the AMT fields for ID= 2,3 and 4 for CONTRACT =1.
For row 6, this would be summing the AMT fields for ID=2,4 for CONTRACT=2

One caveat is that double counting should not occur (i.e. for row 6, sum the AMT fields for ID=2,4 for CONTRACT=2, do not double count ID=2)

Comment: `Check the HDR_NUM field and get the corresponding AMT value where ID=HDR_NUM AND the CONTRACT field is the same ` This is **really** unclear. What does "where ID=HDR_NUM AND the CONTRACT field is the same" *actually* mean? Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: I mean that the AMT value needs to be retrieved from the row where ID=HDR_NUM. Given that that the actual data set contains 1000s of contracts (which can have the same ID #s), I want to make sure that the record where the ID matches has the same value in the Contract field as well.

Comment: But for the first row (ID = 1), there are only 2 rows where HDR_NUM = 1, i.e. AMT = 0.00 & 0.87, so that total should be 0.87.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
def F(s):
    rule1   = s[['ID', 'AMT']].set_index('ID').to_dict()['AMT']
    rule2   = s[['REL_NUM', 'AMT']].groupby('REL_NUM').sum().to_dict()['AMT']
    s1 = s['HDR_NUM'].astype(int).map(rule1).fillna(0)
    s2 = s['HDR_NUM'].astype(int).map(rule2).fillna(0)
    return s1 + s2

df['CALCULATION'] = df.groupby('CONTRACT').apply(F).values.ravel()


    CONTRACT    ID  AMT     REL_NUM HDR_NUM CALCULATION
0   1           1   0.00    0       1       36.39
1   1           2   33.85   1       2       34.57
2   1           3   0.72    2       2       34.57
3   1           4   0.87    1       1       36.39
4   1           5   1.67    1       2       34.57
```

Comment: thanks! But I am not getting the correct output. I updated the question to include the actual data and expected output vs what I am getting using the solution you mentioned. Any ideas?

Comment: @babz I didn't know you could have more than one value for RE_NUM. Updated the code